# How to exclude documentation folder from eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, jsdoc, eslintignore

I am creating documentation in a React app (using web-pack) by running the following command,

```
jsdoc src -r -d docs
```

This creates a folder on the root of the app called `docs`.

However when I run `npm test sometest.test.js`, eslint runs before the test and throws a long list of errors because it runs on the `docs` folder. I have tried excluding `docs` folder from eslint by adding it in the .eslintignore file like in the example shared below.

.eslintignore

```
docs/*
```

But still I see a long list of errors created by eslint on the `docs` folder. Errors shown below,

```
3:7 error unnecessary escape character: \> no-useless-escape
...
```

How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `docs/`  or `docs/**` perhaps? Just throwing some ideas since your concept seems okay

Comment: Nope. It didnt worked. By any chance is it about the versions that I am using? Using eslint 4.19.1

Comment: Huh... the newest version is 7.10.0, so you are due to update soon, but I am still not 100% sure it is related to the version, but have you tried using `ignorePatterns`? You can add `docs/*` in the array as you would in the `.eslintignore` file https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignorepatterns-in-config-files

Comment: Ignore-pattern in the file did not work for some reason. However upon adding the ignore pattern in package.json did worked. But that too not directly. Worked as a prehook